# How can you use Postgresql's is contained by (@>) and contains (<@) in hibernate?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I am trying to compare a provided array with a the values of a text[] column in Postgresql using hibernate.
This seems to be kind of tricky.

## What I have tried so far:

### Hibernate dialect

I tried to register a function in the postgres dialect:

```
registerFunction("array_in_array", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN, "?1 @> ?2"));
```

and then try to write query as such:

```
from MyTable mt where (array_in_array(:arr, mt.arr)) = true
```

When executing the query providing a **String[]** parameter I get following error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bytea @> text[]
>
> Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

When executing the query providing a **List** parameter I get following error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying @> character varying
>
> Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

It suggests to use explicit type casts, so I did. Resulting following error:

With String[]

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot cast type bytea to text[]

and with List:

> org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer HHH000174: Function template anticipated 1 arguments, but 2 arguments encountered
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1.

Also tried to use a native query. Resulting in the same errors.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you been able to execute this function/query outside of hybernate? Based on the error provided, it seems like the error occurs at a lower level.

Comment: Yes, I could run it natively without problems. It seems that hibernate doesn't convert the list or array to the correct text[] type.
He converts list to separate text arguments, and arrays to bytea.

Comment: That's not uncommon, for example date conversions to/from text don't happen automatically when a query executes via jdbc, but work fine from psql. You can solve that with explicit casts to text.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem recently. One possible workaround is to pass a string and use a built-in postgres function to create an array out of it.

So the custom function would look like this:

```
registerFunction("array_in_array", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN, "?1 @> string_to_array(?2, ',')"));
```

where the second argument is a String of comma-separated values from the original list/array.

Looks a little bit hacky, but in terms of performance should be just fine for most applications.